# Why the function written is making the text blank instead of replacing <br> tag by \n in following scenario?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, newline, line-breaks

I've one variable, say `$text` as follows :

```
$text = "Line one <br>Line two<br>Line threee<br>Line Fourrr<br>Line Fiveee";
```

I've written one function called `function br2nl()` as follows :

```
  function br2nl($buff = '') {
    $buff = mb_convert_encoding($buff, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $buff = preg_replace('#<br[/\s]*>#si', "\n", $buff);
    $buff = trim($buff);

    return $buff;
  }
```

Following is the call to the function :

```
$text = br2nl($text);
```

Now if I `echo $text;` I'm getting blank. The expected result should be all the `<br>` tags get replaced by `<\n>`. The expected output should be as follows :

```
 "Line one\nLine two\nLine threee\nLine Fourrr\nLine Fiveee"
```

So what should I do?

Comment: Code works fine for me! Also do you want to use `\n` or `<\n>` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 :  I want \n

Comment: 1. Please make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code 2. What is the **exact** output of: `$text = br2nl($text); var_dump($text);` (Take the output from the source code)?

Comment: preg_replace("<br />", "/\\n/m",  $string);
Use the above given code. hope it may work .

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia You know that the second argument isn't a regex?!